# What is a user thread and a kernel thread?

Tags: threads, threading

I know what a thread is, and I know how they work, but I'm quite confused as to what a *user thread* and a *kernel thread* are in terms of what they are allowed to do.

Can you please clarify what a user thread can do and what a kernel thread can do?

Comment: This question has already been answered on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957570/kernel-space-vs-user-space

Comment: Well the question has been asked but not properly answered. All that was answered from the 5 or 6 things the person asked was about User space and Kernel space.

Comment: I think the definition from Dave Rager is concise and precise: "Kernel space and user space is the separation of the privileged operating system functions and the restricted user applications. "

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> A kernel thread, sometimes called a LWP (Lightweight Process) is
>   created and scheduled by the kernel. Kernel threads are often more
>   expensive to create than user threads and the system calls to directly
>   create kernel threads are very platform specific.
>
> A user thread is normally created by a threading library and
>   scheduling is managed by the threading library itself (Which runs in
>   user mode). All user threads belong to process that created them. The
>   advantage of user threads is that they are portable. The major
>   difference can be seen when using multiprocessor systems, user threads
>   completely managed by the threading library can't be ran in parallel
>   on the different CPUs, although this means they will run fine on
>   uniprocessor systems. Since kernel threads use the kernel scheduler,
>   different kernel threads can run on different CPUs. Many systems
>   implement threading differently,
>
> A many-to-one threading model maps many user processes directly to one
>   kernel thread, the kernel thread can be thought of as the main
>   process. A one-to-one threading model maps each user thread directly
>   to one kernel thread, this model allows parallel processing on the
>   multiprocessor systems. Each kernel thread can be thought of as a VP
>   (Virtual Process) which is managed by the scheduler.

Source:
[Answers](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_difference_between_user_level_threads_and_kernel_level_threads)

Also you can found info in wikipedia chapter 3 - 3 Processes, kernel threads, user threads, and fibers:

[Thread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29)

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to copy with apparently not knowing exactly what the argument is really about and without knowing completely the answer. Isn't a LWP usually created on top of a kernel thread as a bridge between this last one and the user thread? Also, this answer is very confusing because it keeps switching terminology, and at the end you don't understand if for example a kernel thread is a process, etc.