# Why do process names start with the letter k in Linux?

Tags: linux, process

When using the `top` command on a linux server, I can see multiple root processes starting with the letter **k**, like for example `kthreadd`, `kblockd`, `khelper`, `kacpi_notify`, `ksmd`, `kswapd0`, `khugepaged`, `ksmd` and much more.

I assume it's not a coincidence; what does the **k** stand for here?

Comment: A bit googling tells you "kernel"

Comment: @deviantfan I guessed "k" for "kernel" without googling :)

Comment: @DavidPostill That was meant as a hint to OP that writing questions for this is not necessary, not that we all need Google for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those aren’t processes but [kernel threads](http://www.tldp.org/FAQ/Threads-FAQ/Types.html):

> Threads are "light weight processes" (LWPs). [...]
>
> [...]
>
> Kernel-space threads often are implemented in the kernel using several tables (each task gets a table of threads). In this case, the kernel schedules each thread within the timeslice of each process. There is a little more overhead with mode switching from user->kernel-> user and loading of larger contexts, but initial performance measures indicate a negligible increase in time.
>
> Advantages. Since the clocktick will determine the switching times, a task is less likely to hog the timeslice from the other threads within the task. Also I/O blocking is not a problem. Lastly, if properly coded, the process automatically can take advantage of SMPs and will run incrementally faster with each added CPU.

[Related reading](https://superuser.com/q/455316/219095)